# Parsing parameters for a potential function using parsimonious

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, parsing

Question originally asked on [code review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/219729). Asking it here again by recommendation.

---

### Background

A [forcefield](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/219729) is a collection of functions and parameters that is used to calculate the potential energy of a complex system. I have text files which contain data about the parameters for a forcefield. The text file is split into many sections, with each section following the same format:

- A section header which is enclosed in square brackets
- On the next line the word `indices:` followed by a list of integers.
- This is then followed by 1 or more lines of parameters associated with the section

Here is a made-up example file to showcase the format.

```
############################################
# Comments begin with '#'
############################################

[lj_pairs] # Section 1
    indices:    0 2
#  ID      eps    sigma
    1       2.344   1.234   5
    2       4.423   5.313   5
    3       1.573   6.321   5
    4       1.921   11.93   5

[bonds]
indices:    0 1
    2   4.234e-03   11.2
    6   -0.134545   5.7
```

The goal is to parse such files and store all of the information in a `dict`.

---

Currently, I have the following code to accomplish my task

```
""" Force-field data reader """

import re
from dataclasses import dataclass, field
from typing import Dict, Iterable, List, TextIO, Tuple, Union, Any


def ff_reader(fname: Union[str, TextIO]) -> Dict[str, "FFSections"]:
    """ Reads data from a force-field file """

    try:
        if _is_string(fname):
            fh = open(fname, mode="r")
            own = True
        else:
            fh = iter(fname)
    except TypeError:
        raise ValueError("fname must be a string or a file handle")

    # All the possible section headers
    keywords = ("lj_pairs", "bonds")  # etc... Long list of possible sections
                                      # Removed for brevity
    re_sections = re.compile(r"^\[(%s)\]$" % "|".join(keywords))
    ff_data = _strip_comments(fh)
    # Empty dict that'll hold all the data.
    final_ff_data = {key: FFSections() for key in keywords}

    # Get first section header
    for line in ff_data:
        match = re.match(re_sections, line)
        if match:
            section = match.group(1)
            in_section_for_first_time = True
            break
        else:
            raise FFReaderError("A valid section header must be the first line in file")
    else:
        raise FFReaderError("No force-field sections exist")

    # Read the rest of the file
    for line in ff_data:

        match = re.match(re_sections, line)

        # If we've encounted a section header the next line must be an index list.
        if in_section_for_first_time:
            if line.split()[0] != "indices:":
                raise FFReaderError(f"Missing index list for section: {section}")
            idx = _validate_indices(line)
            final_ff_data[section].use_idx = idx
            in_section_for_first_time = False
            in_params_for_first_time = True
            continue

        if match and in_params_for_first_time:
            raise FFReaderError(
                f"Section {section} missing parameters"
                + "Sections must contain atleast one type coefficients"
            )

        if match:  # and not in_section_for_first_time and in_params_for_first_time
            section = match.group(1)
            in_section_for_first_time = True
            continue

        params = _validate_params(line)
        final_ff_data[section].coeffs.update([params])
        in_params_for_first_time = False

    # Close the file if we opened it
    if own:
        fh.close()

    for section in final_ff_data.values():
        # coeff must exist if use_idx does
        if section.use_idx is not None:
            assert section.coeffs

    return final_ff_data

def _strip_comments(
    instream: TextIO, comments: Union[str, Iterable[str], None] = "#"
) -> Iterable[str]:
    """ Strip comments from a text IO stream """

    if comments is not None:
        if isinstance(comments, str):
            comments = [comments]
        comments_re = re.compile("|".join(map(re.escape, comments)))
    else:
        comments_re = ".*"
    try:
        for lines in instream.readlines():
            line = re.split(comments_re, lines, 1)[0].strip()
            if line != "":
                yield line
    except AttributeError:
        raise TypeError("instream must be a `TextIO` stream") from None


@dataclass(eq=False)
class FFSections:
    """
    FFSections(coeffs,use_idx)

    Container for forcefield information
    """

    coeffs: Dict[int, List[float]] = field(default_factory=dict)
    use_idx: List[int] = field(default=None)


class FFReaderError(Exception):
    """ Incorrect or badly formatted force-Field data """

    def __init__(self, message: str, badline: Optional[str] = None) -> None:
        if badline:
            message = f"{message}\nError parsing --> ({badline})"
        super().__init__(message)


def _validate_indices(line: str) -> List[int]:
    """
    Check if given line contains only a whitespace separated
    list of integers
    """
    # split on indices: followed by whitescape
    split = line.split("indices:")[1].split()
    # import ipdb; ipdb.set_trace()
    if not set(s.isdecimal() for s in split) == {True}:
        raise FFReaderError(
            "Indices should be integers and seperated by whitespace", line
        )
    return [int(x) for x in split]


def _validate_params(line: str) -> Tuple[int, List[float]]:
    """
    Check if given line is valid param line, which are
    an integer followed by one or more floats seperated by whitespace
    """
    split = line.split()
    id_ = split[0]
    coeffs = split[1:]
    if not id_.isdecimal():
        raise FFReaderError("Invalid params", line)
    try:
        coeffs = [float(x) for x in coeffs]
    except (TypeError, ValueError):
        raise FFReaderError("Invalid params", line) from None
    return (int(id_), coeffs)
```

---

### Question

This seems like a lot of code to accomplish a simple task. How can I use `parsimonious` or similar parsing libraries to simplify parsing such files?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As stated in the other answer you can use a parsing library such as `parsimonious` in combination with a `NodeVisitor` class:

```
from parsimonious.grammar import Grammar
from parsimonious.nodes import NodeVisitor

data = """
############################################
# Comments begin with '#'
############################################

[lj_pairs] # Section 1
    indices:    0 2
    #  ID      eps    sigma
    1       2.344   1.234   5
    2       4.423   5.313   5
    3       1.573   6.321   5
    4       1.921   11.93   5

[bonds]
indices:    0 1
    2   4.234e-03   11.2
    6   -0.134545   5.7
"""

grammar = Grammar(
    r"""
    expr        = (entry / garbage)+
    entry       = section garbage indices (valueline / garbage)*
    section     = lpar word rpar

    indices     = ws? "indices:" values+
    garbage     = ((comment / hs)* newline?)*

    word        = ~"\w+"

    values      = number+
    valueline   = values newline?

    number      = hs? ~"[-.e\d]+" hs?

    lpar        = "["
    rpar        = "]"

    comment     = ~"#.+"
    ws          = ~"\s*"
    hs          = ~"[\t\ ]*"

    newline     = ~"[\r\n]"
    """
)

tree = grammar.parse(data)

class DataVisitor(NodeVisitor):
    def visit_number(self, node, visited_children):
        """ Returns integer and float values. """
        _, value, _ = visited_children
        try:
            number = int(value.text)
        except ValueError:
            number = float(value.text)
        return number

    def visit_section(self, node, visited_children):
        """ Returns the section as text. """
        _, section, _ = visited_children
        return section.text

    def visit_indices(self, node, visited_children):
        """ Returns the index numbers. """
        *_, values = visited_children
        return values[0]

    def visit_valueline(self, node, visited_children):
        """ Returns every value from one line. """
        values, _ = visited_children
        return values

    def visit_entry(self, node, visited_children):
        """ Returns one entry (section, indices, values). """
        section, _, indices, lst = visited_children
        values = [item[0] for item in lst if item[0]]

        return (section, {'indices': indices, 'values': values})

    def visit_expr(self, node, visited_children):
        """ Returns the whole structure as a dict. """
        return dict([item[0] for item in visited_children if item[0]])

    def visit_garbage(self, node, visited_children):
        """ You know what this does. """
        return None

    def generic_visit(self, node, visited_children):
        """ Returns the visited children (if any) or the node itself. """
        return visited_children or node

d = DataVisitor()
result = d.visit(tree)
print(result)
```

This will yield

```
{
 'lj_pairs': {'indices': [0, 2], 'values': [[1, 2.344, 1.234, 5], [2, 4.423, 5.313, 5], [3, 1.573, 6.321, 5], [4, 1.921, 11.93, 5]]}, 
 'bonds': {'indices': [0, 1], 'values': [[2, 0.004234, 11.2], [6, -0.134545, 5.7]]}
}
```

---

## Explanation

Your original data file can be seen as a `DSL` - a **d**omain **s**pecific **l**anguage. We therfore need a grammar which describes how your format is allowed to look like. A usual way here is to first formulate small bricks, such as whitespace or a "word".

---

In [**`parsimonious`**](https://github.com/erikrose/parsimonious) we have several options, one being to specify regular expressions (these start with a `~`):

```
ws          = ~"\s*"
```

Here, `ws` stands for `\s*` which is zero or more whitespaces.

---

Another possibility is to literally form a part, such as

```
lpar        = "["
```

---

The last - and most powerful - possibility is to *combine* both of these smaller parts to form a bigger one, such as

```
section     = lpar word rpar
```

which translates to `[word_characters_HERE123]` or a similar structure.

---

Now the normal alternations (`/`) and quantifiers apply, such as `*` (zero ore more, greedy), `+` (one ore more, greedy) and `?` (zero or one, greedy) and can be put after every expression we might think of.

---

If everything works fine and the grammar is suitable for the data we have, everything is parsed into a tree structure, a so called **a**bstract **s**yntax **t**ree (AST). In order to actually do sth. useful with this structure (e.g. make a nice `dict` out of it), we need to feed it into a `NodeVisitor` class. This is the pendant to our previously formed grammar insofar as the methods `visit_*` will call every leaf suitable for it. That is to say, a method `visit_section(...)` will be called on every `section` leaf with its appropriate `visited_children`.

Let's make this more clear. The function

```
    def visit_section(self, node, visited_children):
        """ Returns the section as text. """
        _, section, _ = visited_children
        return section.text
```

will be called for the `section` part of our grammar (`lpar section rpar`), so the leaf `section` has these three children. We are not interested in neither the `[` nor the `]` but only the section text itself, so we do some unpacking and return the `section.text`.

We need to do this for every node / leaf we previously defined. By default, the first definition (in our case `expr`) and the corresponding `visit_expr(...)` will be the output of the `NodeVisitor` class and all other nodes are children (grandchildren, great grandchildren, etc.) of this node.